# Finding the rating of words using python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This is my program and it display the value if i give the complete name like if i type `eng` than it will show me only `eng` with value

```
import re
sent = "eng"
#sent=raw_input("Enter word")
#regex = re.compile('(^|\W)sent(?=(\W|$))')
for line in open("sir_try.txt").readlines():
    if sent == line.split()[0].strip():
        k = line.rsplit(',',1)[0].strip()
        print k
gene name        utr length
ensbta                  24
ensg1                   12
ensg24                  30
ensg37                  65
enscat                  22
ensm                    30
```

Actually what i want to do is that i want to search the `highest value from the text file` not through words , and it delete all the values from the text file of the same word having less value than the maximum like from the above text it should delete `12 , 30` for ensg , and than `it should find the minimum value from the utr values and display it with name`
What you people answering me is , i already done it , and i mention it before my showing my program

Comment: So, you want to keep only one "sequence" containing `ensg`, the one with the maximum on the other field??

Comment: I just want that if want than it give me the result from maximum value like 65 of ensg37 as from txt file above , it should check numbers and than show string of that number

Comment: I have added the deletion part, check if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
file=open("sir_try.txt","r")
list_line=file.readlines()
file.close()
all_text=""

dic={}
sent="ensg"
temp_list=[]
for line in list_line:
    all_text=all_text+line
    name= line.rsplit()[0].strip()
    score=line.rsplit()[1].strip()
    dic[name]=score
for i in dic.keys():
    if sent in i:
        temp_list.append(dic[i])
hiegh_score=max(temp_list)

def check(index):
    reverse_text=all_text[index+1::-1]
    index2=reverse_text.find("\n")
    if sent==reverse_text[:index2+1][::-1][1:len(sent)+1]:
        return False
    else:
        return True

list_to_min=dic.values()
for i in temp_list:
    if i!=hiegh_score:
        index=all_text.find(str(i))
        while check(index):
            index=all_text.find(str(i),index+len(str(i)))
        all_text=all_text[0:index]+all_text[index+len(str(i)):]
        list_to_min.remove(str(i))
#write all text to "sir_try.txt"
file2=open("sir_try.txt","w")
file2.write(all_text)
file2.close()
min_score= min(list_to_min)
for j in dic.keys():
    if min_score==dic[j]:
        print "min score is :"+str(min_score)+" for person "+j
```

function check is for a bug in solotion for explain when your file is

```
gene name        utr length
ali                     12
ali87                   30
ensbta                  24
ensg1                   12
ensg24                  30
ensg37                  65
enscat                  22
ensm                    30
```

program delete ali score but we dont have it
by adding check function i solve it
and this version is final version answer

Comment: it should find the minimum value from the utr values and display it with name

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of `if sent ==` and replace it with a `if sent in (line.split()[0].strip()):`

That should check if the value of sent (engs) is anywhere in the argument (line.split()[0].strip()) in this case.

If you're still trying to only take the highest value, I would just create a variable value, then something along the lines of

```
if line.split()[1].strip() > value:
    value = line.split()[1].strip()
```

Test that out and let us know how it works for you.

Comment: `if line.split[1].strip() > value:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` for using the function `if line.split[1].strip() > value:
    value = line.split[1].strip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
f = open('./sir_try.txt', 'r')
f = f.readlines()
del f[0]

gene = {}
matched_gene = {}

for line in f:
    words = line.strip().split(' ')
    words = [word for word in words if not word == '']
    gene[words[0]] = words[1]

# getting user input
user_input = raw_input('Enter gene name: ')
for gene_name, utr_length in gene.iteritems():
    if user_input in gene_name:
        matched_gene[gene_name] = utr_length
m = max(matched_gene.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
print m, matched_gene[m]  # expected answer

# code to remove redundant gene names as per requirement

for key in matched_gene.keys():
    if not key == m:
        matched_gene.pop(key)
for key in gene.keys():
    if user_input in key:
        gene.pop(key)

final_gene = dict(gene.items() + matched_gene.items())
out = open('./output.txt', 'w')
out.write('gene name' + '\t\t' + 'utr length' + '\n\n')
for key, value in final_gene.iteritems():
    out.write(key + '\t\t\t\t' + value + '\n')
out.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Enter gene name: ensg
ensg37 65
```

Comment: But it didn't delete other values of ensg37 from the text file , the same word having values less than 65

Comment: your answer is based on one part , the 2nd part is ,` and than it should find the minimum value from the output file utr values and display it with name `

Comment: you focus on user input and iam focusing on that user should not enter the value , system check on its own , through checking values , not words , as i highlight my question again , you people give me the answer of what i already have done (approx)

Answer (score 0):

To find out the name (first column) with the maximum value associated (second column), you need to first [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the lines at the whitespace between name and value. Then you can find the maximum value using the built-in [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function. Let it take the value column as sorting criterion. You can then easily find out the corresponding name.

Example:

```
file_content = """
gene name        utr length
ensbta                  24
ensg1                   12
ensg24                  30
ensg37                  65
enscat                  22
ensm                    30
"""

# split lines at whitespace
l = [line.split() for line in file_content.splitlines()]

# skip headline and empty lines
l = [line for line in l if len(line) == 2]

print l

# find the maximum of second column
max_utr_length_tuple = max(l, key=lambda x:x[1])

print max_utr_length_tuple

print max_utr_length_tuple[0]
```

the output is:

```
$ python test.py
[['ensbta', '24'], ['ensg1', '12'], ['ensg24', '30'], ['ensg37', '65'], ['enscat', '22'], ['ensm', '30']]
['ensg37', '65'] 
ensg37
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet:

```
In [01]: t=file_content.split()[4:]
In [02]: b=((zip(t[0::2], t[1::2])))
In [03]: max(b, key=lambda x:x[1])
Out[03]: ('ensg37', '65')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged  your question [regex](/questions/tagged/regex),
Here's something that you would want to see and it's the only one (at the moment) that uses regex!

```
import re

sent = 'ensg' # your sequence
# regex that will "filter" the lines containing value of sent  
my_re = re.compile(r'(.*?%s.*?)\s+?(\d+)' % sent)

with open('stack.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read() # get data from file

filtered = my_re.findall(lines) # "filter" your data
print filtered

# get the desired (tuple with maximum "utr length")
max_tuple = max(filtered, key=lambda x: x[1]) 
print max_tuple
```

Output:

```
[('ensg1', '12'), ('ensg24', '30'), ('ensg37', '65')]
('ensg37', '65')
```